# VBA 2 dimension arrays: Compare Sheet1 vs Sheet2 and assign value to Sheet1 based on searching criteria

Tags: vba

[image]

The below is my code. I have tried many different solutions but none seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Sub MultiDimensiionArray1()

```
'array for sheet one and sheet two
Dim myArraySheet1(0 To 3, 0 To 4) As Variant
Dim myArraySheet2(0 To 5, 0 To 4) As Variant

Dim i As Long, j As Long ' dimension counter for for sheet one
Dim Dimension1 As Long, Dimension2 As Long ' dimension counter for for sheet one

'number of rows in sheet one
Dim x As Integer, NumRows As Integer
    Sheet1.Activate
    NumRows = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    'store everything on sheet one in array
    For i = LBound(myArraySheet1, 1) To UBound(myArraySheet1, 1)
        For j = LBound(myArraySheet1, 2) To UBound(myArraySheet1, 2)
            myArraySheet1(i, j) = Range("A2").Offset(i, j).Value

        Next j

    Next i


    'store everything on sheet two in array
    Sheet2.Activate

    For Dimension1 = LBound(myArraySheet2, 1) To UBound(myArraySheet2, 1)
        For Dimension2 = LBound(myArraySheet2, 2) To UBound(myArraySheet2, 2)

            myArraySheet2(Dimension1, Dimension2) = Range("A2").Offset(Dimension1, Dimension2).Value

        Next Dimension2

    Next Dimension1
```

'READ FROM ARRAY/OR DISPLAY  THE RESULT
        Sheet1.Activate
    ' Select sheet one cell G2
        Range("G2").Select
    ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
              For x = 1 To NumRows

```
                   For i = LBound(myArraySheet1, 1) To UBound(myArraySheet1, 1)
                        For j = LBound(myArraySheet1, 2) To UBound(myArraySheet1, 2)

                                For Dimension1 = LBound(myArraySheet2, 1) To UBound(myArraySheet2, 1)

                                    For Dimension2 = LBound(myArraySheet2, 2) To UBound(myArraySheet2, 2)

                                                'if sheet one row equal to sheet two row execute the below code
                                                 If myArraySheet1(i, j) = myArraySheet2(Dimension1, Dimension2) Then
                                                        ActiveCell.Value = "YES IT IS DUPE AND NOT RESOLVED"
                                                        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                                                        ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = 2

                                                        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                                                 Else
                                                    ActiveCell.Value = "Brand New"
                                                    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                                                    ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = 2

                                                 End If
                                      Next Dimension2

                                Next Dimension1
                        Next j
                        Next i

        Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not use array but the code below give you the expected output that you want:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long, Lastrow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, c As Integer
Dim FOUND As Boolean


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

Lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

i = 2
Do
FOUND = False

        For j = 2 To Lastrow2

                For c = 1 To 5

                    If ws1.Cells(i, c).Value = ws2.Cells(j, c).Value Then

                                    FOUND = True
                            Else
                                    FOUND = False
                                    Exit For

                        End If

                    Next c

              If FOUND = True Then
                        ws1.Cells(i, 7) = "YES IT IS DUPE AND NOT RESOLVED"
                        Exit For
                End If

        Next j

           If FOUND = False Then

                        ws1.Cells(i, 7) = "Brand new"

            End If

  i = i + 1

Loop While i < Lastrow + 1


End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

With this you'll have two arrays containing values of cells that aren't equal so you'll be able to use the values you need to do what you want

```
Sub Test()
Dim DiffSh1() As Variant
Dim DiffSh2() As Variant
Call Compare_Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2"), DiffSh1, DiffSh2)
'Now you can use the values in the two arrays as you need
For x = LBound(DiffSh1, 1) To UBound(DiffSh1, 1)
    For y = LBound(DiffSh1, 2) To UBound(DiffSh1, 2)
    If DiffSh1(x, y) <> "" Then
        MsgBox ("Cell at Row " & x & " Column " & y & " isn't equal:" & vbCrLf & _
            "Value in sheet1 is: " & DiffSh1(x, y) & vbCrLf & _
            "Value in sheet2 is: " & DiffSh2(x, y))
    End If
    Next y
Next x
End Sub

Public Sub Compare_Sheets(ByVal Sh1 As Worksheet, ByVal Sh2 As Worksheet, ByRef DiffIn1() As Variant, ByRef DiffIn2() As Variant)
    Dim LastCol
    Dim LastRow
    LastCol = Sh1.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    If Sh2.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column > LastCol Then
        LastCol = Sh2.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    End If
    LastRow = Sh1.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    If Sh2.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row > LastRow Then
        LastRow = Sh2.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    End If
ReDim DiffIn1(1 To LastRow, 1 To LastCol)
ReDim DiffIn2(1 To LastRow, 1 To LastCol)
Dim mCol As Long, mRow As Long
For mCol = 1 To LastCol
    For mRow = 1 To LastRow
        If Sh1.Cells(mRow, mCol) <> Sh2.Cells(mRow, mCol) Then
            DiffIn1(mRow, mCol) = Sh1.Cells(mRow, mCol).Value
            DiffIn2(mRow, mCol) = Sh2.Cells(mRow, mCol).Value
        Else
            DiffIn1(mRow, mCol) = ""
            DiffIn2(mRow, mCol) = ""
        End If
    Next mRow
Next mCol
End Sub
```